# Postman - How do I loop a request in another request's test script?

Tags: loops, request, postman

I have a request that returns an array and I, thanks to StackOverflow, figured out how to make each object in the array its own environment variable. Now I want to make a request per variable in the same request as I instantiated the variable. Here is what I got:

```
var a = pm.response.json();

for (i = 0;i < a.sick_beats.length; i++){
    pm.environment.unset("Beat_" + (i+1));
    pm.environment.set("Beat_" + (i+1), a.sick_beats[i]);
    pm.sendRequest("Publish Beat");
}
```

It sends the request "Publish Beat" but uses it as the URL instead of referencing the request.

I guess my question is how can I reference a request name instead of a URL, since the old way `postman.setNextRequest("Request_Name");` doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using this in the Collection Runner? `setNextRequest` doesn't work for single requests.

Comment: That... makes a lot of sense. I am not using the Collection Runner, by the way.

Comment: If you're able to attach more Postman images of what you have, i'll be able to give you a better answer. Also, in your code `pm.response.json()` will do the same as `JSON.parse(responseBody)`.

Comment: I wish I could but I can't. I did fix that error that you pointed out, so thanks!

Comment: With what you've posted, it's difficult for people to suggest solutions. Check out the Postman Documentation and Blog for more information.

Comment: The collection runner only runs a set amount of iterations but I need this to run as many times as there are sick_beats. And I would preferably like to stay out of the Collection Runner since I have never used it. Which brings me back to the question at hand, how do I reference a request name in pm.setRequest();

Comment: Added my answer to the bottom. I don't see it working, like you what it too without using the Collection Runner - You need to read more about the tool.

Answer (score 1):

This pm.* function doesn't work in this way:

```
pm.sendRequest("Publish Beat")
```

Check out this [blog](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/10/03/send-asynchronous-requests-with-postmans-pm-api/) from Postman explaining it more.

This is a basic extract from the `snippets` in the application. The first arg is the URL.

```
pm.sendRequest("https://postman-echo.com/get", function (err, response) {
    console.log(response.json());
});
```

You can use `pm.setNextRequest('request_name')` to create a workflow but this will only work in the Collection Runner and not for single requests. You can add a collection of requests and chain these together using the `{{Beat_1}}` variable in the URL.

Alternatively, you could add something like this but it's **very** hacky and wouldn't ever send requests over and over again, like the collection runner would:

```
var some_value = pm.environment.get('Beat_whatever')
pm.sendRequest(`https://your-super-secret-site.com/${some_value}`, (err, response) => {
    // This is just here so you can see the response
    console.log(response.json())
})
```